# Jquery SlideToggle Different Div

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, slidetoggle

today i have this problem. i wrote an easy normal script in php for take the information (in this case news) from a db, then i thinked to use Jquery for toggle news but it isn't working as i want... practically i would that when i click on a news title the news content will toggle on then if you click again the title of the news the news content will be toggle off... this is the script:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script>   
           $(document).ready(function(){
     $('.tit_news').click(function(){
        $('.cont_news').slideToggle();
        });
      });
</script>
</head>
</html>
<?php 
$query="SELECT * FROM tablename";
$do=mssql_query($query);
while($news=mssql_fetch_array($do)){
echo '<div class="tit_news">'.$news['title'].'</div><br /><div class="cont_news">'.$news['text'].'</div><hr>';
}
?>
```

But this have the problem that when i click a news title ALL the news are toggle on...i would make that only the content of the news i click would toggle on

Answer (score 0):

Change your jQuery to this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.tit_news').click(function(){
       $('.cont_news', this).slideToggle();
   });
});
```

$('.cont_news') matches ALL instances of .cont_news, whereas $('.cont_news', this) is the same as $(this).find('.cont_news').

Comment: Oops, I didn't realize you had replied to this. Is it still an issue?